# How to install older version of azure service fabric SDK (after uninstalling latest version)?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I recently upgraded to 5.3.301 version of azure service fabric runtime on my local developer machine. Then I uninstalled it and tried to go back to previous version of 5.1.163. It seems that I can not go back because the web platform invoker no longer has the previous version (5.1.163) listed as one of the options.

Is there a way to go back to previous version of service fabric runtime? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the links. Install in this order:

1. Runtime:
   http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/9/6/C9680A4C-291F-4A6F-B699-26FF704577BA/MicrosoftServiceFabric.5.1.163.9590.msi
2. SDK:
       http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/9/6/C9680A4C-291F-4A6F-B699-26FF704577BA/MicrosoftServiceFabricSDK.2.1.163.msi
3. VS Tools:
       http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/7/6/E76A0B84-6DAB-4734-85E2-5912A1130FB4/MicrosoftAzureServiceFabricTools.VS140.en-us.msi

Comment: I need this for version 2.4.164, does anyone know the direct links for it?

Comment: how about the link for 2.4.145?

Comment: Runtime: http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/B/4/9B437FCC-E78F-4DAA-A2D8-CC5A5BF9E76F/MicrosoftServiceFabric.5.4.145.9494.msi
SDK: http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/B/4/9B437FCC-E78F-4DAA-A2D8-CC5A5BF9E76F/MicrosoftServiceFabricSDK.2.4.145.msi
Tools: http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/B/4/9B437FCC-E78F-4DAA-A2D8-CC5A5BF9E76F/MicrosoftAzureServiceFabricTools.VS140.en-us.msi

Comment: How do you find runtimes?  I need the latest one.

Comment: They usually are part of the release notes. Check the service fabric team blog for release notes. e.g. https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2018/10/Microsoft-Azure-Service-Fabric-Refresh-2-Release-Notes-SDK-3.x-Runtime-6.3.pdf

Comment: how did you find these? I need "Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio 2015 1.8.51024.1" it is for SDK 3.2.162

Answer (score 2):

"I need this for version 2.4.164"

I don't have direct link for 2.4.164 but the web installer seems to have it:
 http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx?command=getinstallerredirect&appid=MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-VS2015-2_1

Go to products tab then search for "fabric" query and you will get a choice between 2.4.164 and 2.5.216